# How to bind Ctrl-Tab and Ctrl-Shift-Tab in tmux for mintty

Tags: tmux, mintty

I would like to bind <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> (without prefix) to tmux functions, under minTTY/cygwin.

I have tried the following tmux configuration:

```
set-option -gw xterm-keys on
bind-key -n C-Tab next-window
bind-key -n "^[[1;5I" next-window # tmux doesn't recognize
bind-key -n "\e[1;5I" next-window # tmux doesn't recognize
```

If I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> after launching tmux, I get a bell sound. If I hit it after the tmux prefix, it prints `1;5I`.

I am using minTTY 2.2.3 under cygwin/Babun. I have disabled minTTY's handling of this key combo via its options (`SwitchShortcuts=no` in `.minttyrc`).

For reference, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> work for cycling `screen` windows with the following .screenrc:

```
bindkey "^[[1;5I" next
bindkey "^[[1;6I" prev
```

Answer (score 6):

I got here because I bumped into the same issue.

tmux now supports custom key bindings via `user-keys` - since August 2017, so if you can build tmux yourself, or once a new tmux version is released, it's possible like so:

```
set -s user-keys[0] "\e[1;5I"
set -s user-keys[1] "\e[1;6I"
bind-key -n User0 select-pane -t+
bind-key -n User1 select-pane -t-
```

Note that you must use double quotes and not single quotes or else it won't interpret `\e` correctly.

At the time of writing the example in the manual uses single quotes - https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1043 , though it's likely to be fixed soon.

Comment: This now works with the current release of tmux (2.6) so you no longer have to build it yourself. I had to dig around a bit to get iTerm2 to send the codes in the first place but I guess that is out of the scope of this question.